# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I am having trouble with quite the common

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)**

error. Even though I looked a lot of them up here, I can´t find an issue that applies to my problem.

Here is the thing. I am loading a .csv file and have no problem loading the data into a dataframe and have a look at them. As soon as I apply a method to the dataframe to format certain columns based on their value I get the error shown above.

I tried to replicate the error in a little example to show you the problem, but in the litte example everything worked fine, so apparently the problem lies in the .csv file I am loading.

The .csv file is from a german website and also in german if that is of any help.

Here´s the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import HTML


#File path
path='file:///D:/Users/Phython/08_07_2018.csv'    

#load data
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', encoding="utf-8")

#replace metric system
i=3
while i <= len(df):
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
    i+=1

#select columns to apply method on them
columnNamesCondCol = ['%heute', 'Wert heute', '+/- gesamt', '%gesamt', 'Wert seit Kauf']

#format cells based on their value
def color_negative_red(val):
    color = 'black'
    if val < 0 : color = 'red'
    if val > 0 :  color = 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color 

#apply method to dataframe
df=df.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=columnNamesCondCol)

df
```

Comment: Does the error go away if you do not *print out* the result? Then the error lies not in the CSV *reading* but in your output target: your console can only handle plain ASCII text. If that is the case, everything works as designed.

Comment: try suitable encoding type instead of utf-8

Comment: @ usr2564301

I get no error if do not print out the dataframe. Mmhh I don´t get it. I printed the dataframe and everything worked. Only after applying the method I get error, though only the font colour of certain cells has been changed. 

Also I do use jupyter notebook. Can´t jupyter notebook display utf-8!?

Comment: @ Mohamed Thasin: I tried quite a few such as latin-1, ascii, cp850 but none worked but apparently the problem lies in the display capabilites of the console